# The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'FirstApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?) in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace
> 'FirstApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   F:\ASP.NET
> MVC\FirstApp\FirstApp\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 13  16  FirstApp

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using FirstApp.Models;

namespace FirstApp
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService

    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your namespace

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It is comming in visual studio 2013..when i have made first "hello world" program by remove all existing folders from View and Controller

Comment: Provide us with some code. Preferably the line that it is getting thrown on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to help you, it is always best to include as much detail as you can about your problem, and this includes what you are trying to do, the exact question you are asking, what you have tried to do to fix it and any other detail that might be useful to help someone answer.

Comment: Try - using FirstApp.Models

Comment: its already there   using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using FirstApp.Models;

namespace FirstApp
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

Comment: Is any body there...error is coming in Identityconfig.cs file

Answer (score 0):

This is way late to the game, but as long as your code is correct, there is a bug in visual studio 2012 and 2013 that causes VS to loose intellisense and and other settings for no apparent reason. Oh, and MS refuses to fix it. Solution is to close vs, delete the .suo file then reopen vs.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760443/visual-studio-2012-ide-loses-intellisense-and-reference-resolution

Comment: Yeah have this bug. Really loving VS2015 too, shame this has to spoil it.